Puppeteer: cannot get response from popup
I'm using puppeteer to scrape PDFs from a website.
When i find a certain selector i have to .click() on it so that the PDF is somehow generated and displayed on a popup window.
The first problem is that i cannot use the url to directly download the PDF because it's a javascript call.
Another problem is that i'm unable to get the very first HTTPResponse object attached to the popup, that should be the one related to the PDF file.
// omitting the starting settings, goto() and navigations

// click the button that launches a javascript that creates the PDF and opens the popup
await page.$eval('#myselector', elem => elem.click());

// get a reference to the popup (is there a better way to do this?)
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page()))); 
const popup = await newPagePromise;
await popup.setRequestInterception(true);
await popup.bringToFront(); //?!

// writing a file for each response
popup.on('response', async response => {
    const url = response.url();
    response.buffer().then(file => {
        const fileName = url.split('/').pop();
        const filePath = path.resolve('temp/', fileName);
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
        writeStream.write(file);
        console.log('Writing filename: '+filePath+fileName);
    });
});

Most probably i'm too late to intercept the very first REQUEST object that should point me to the PDF.
I think i should setup the popup.on('response') listener before acting on the .click(), the problem is that i cannot do it until i get the popup page.
Any suggestions?
EDIT - adding navigation tips
This is the main page soon after the click, nothing happens here.

Next screenshot: the popup navigation. As soon as i click it opens a new browser window, the only way to see the link to download (green one) is to start the inspection milliseconds after the click, or reloading the popup. Puppeteer only retrieve the favicon.ico resource.

I think i need a way to speed up the popup response listener.
How to start listening before the popup opens?
Thanks!

Please don't omit the navigation. The actual page matters quite a bit since every site has unique, arbitrary behavior. Without having code to run and a site to look at, it's pretty much guesswork and there's no easy way to help, other than to make up an example that probably wouldn't apply to your actual case anyway. Thanks.

@ggorlen: i added the navigation, as you can see it's very poor. Puppeteer skips the very first response from the popup, that's the only one i need to download the PDF. Thanks

I don't see the navigation yet, just // omitting the starting settings, goto() and navigations.

@ggorlen sorry, it's a protected business website, i cannot provide a login

OK, pretty much impossible to help then, unless you can create or find a sample site with the same behavior.
